# How to block TextInput blur on tap on a ScrollView outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I create a `TextInput` with floating autocomplete list. I want to be able for tapping elements on the list without bluring the `TextInput`. How can I do that?

It' s my render at now:

```js
return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        {...textFieldProps}
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={handleInputValueChange}
        onFocus={() => setIsModalIsOpened(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsModalIsOpened(false)}
      />
      {!!matchingSuggestions.length && isModalOpened && (
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.listContainer}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        >
          {matchingSuggestions.map(item => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPressIn={() => handleSuggestionPress(item.normal)}
            >
              <View style={styles.suggestionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{item.normal}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

After repair, I will replace a ScrollView by ListView